# Fuzzing an iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, usb, fuzzing

I'm currently researching how to fuzz Apple devices (specifically an iPhone 4 and an iPad 2). The devices are placed into DFU mode and then accessed using OpeniBoot.

I've read through a good chunk of *Fuzzing: Brute Force Vulnerability Testing*, as well as numerous online articles, but I can't seem to find many good references for how to fuzz USB devices, which I'm assuming the iPhone/iPad are since they are connected to the computer through USB.

1. Can those Apple devices still be considered USB devices (since they are in DFU mode and generally not seen except through the use of application such as iTunes, or in this case OpeniBoot)?
2. Having found something to read specifically on the topic of fuzzing USB drivers (*Lessons Learned from 50 bugs:
   Common USB Driver Vulnerabilities*), are those Apple devices a type of USB driver or is that something completely different? Is that something I should spend my time reading up on for this project?
3. Any resources on writing fuzzers, fuzzers that test USB devices, or anything to do with testing something in DFU mode would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: I would check out the following which was from an initial talk at BlackHat regarding fuzzing USB https://github.com/schumilo/vUSBf

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are looking to "fuzz Apple devices". Are you specifically looking to fuzz the USB connection on them? The wireless network connection? A specific app? Something else?

Comment: munkeyoto: Thanks, I looked into that and I think it'll be helpful!

Comment: Neil Smithline: The goal is to fuzz them through the USB connection that will cause them to crash when brought out of DFU mode. So if a snapshot is taken of a VM running an iPhone in DFU mode, fuzzing data will be uploaded through the USB connection, the device will be taken out of DFU mode and checked to see if any type of bug occurred, and then the snapshot will be restored for the next test. I hope that answers your question!